# Unable to compile Broadcom wireless driver on kernel 4.x update

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, broadcom

I can not manage to get the wifi works when updating my kernel to 4.x.
During the installation, the Broadcom wireless driver failed to compile.

I am getting this error :

> Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE
>   directive which does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that
>   it should not be built. Error! Bad return status for module build on
>   kernel: 4.1.3-040103-generic (x86_64) Consult
>   /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more
>   information.

Has anyone encounter this problem and manage to solve it ?

Comment: Why do you need this kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

The Broadcom wireless driver from stable Ubuntu repositories does not support kernel 4.1 yet.

You can try to install [bcmwl-kernel-source](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) from `wily` repostory.

It is patched for Ubuntu 15.10 and works with 4.0 kernel. May work with 4.1 as well.

Copy the file to your Home folder via terminal

```
cd
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

and run

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Comment: This model can have various wireless adapters. It your case it won't work with `wl` driver.

Comment: @hg8 I updated the answer. Normal `wl` from stable repositories does not, but the one from `wily` does.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as I can and report the result.

Comment: Thanks! It worked great. This solution https://github.com/longsleep/bcmwl-ubuntu worked too (for future reference)

Comment: The URL is no longer valid - returns an error. :(

Comment: @hg8 - You rule the world! Just quickly installed, and got WiFi! Thanks!